# Backslash not rendering properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Backslashes don't seem to work (at least on my computer, ubuntu)

- **Normal text**

  ¯_(ツ)_/¯ (backslash visible in text box, but not rendered)

  [image: text]
- **Between backticks**

  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` (backslash renders as Yen sign, while typing I can see the backslash until the font loads)

  [image: backticks]
- **Code block** `<code> backslash here </code>`

  `¯_(ツ)_/¯` (code blocks behave like text, that is no backslash)

  [image: code]

Comment: This issue mostly doesn't have to do with the Furigana engine, I think the double backslash escape thing being needed is because of how the markdown engine on SE sites is implemented

Comment: When you add the `ツ` character in `pre` or `code` tags, the Furigana engine does detect it as being Japanese and displays the whole tag in a Japanese monospaced font.  Many Japanese fonts+Japanese-localized computers display backslashes as yen symbols, this is a historical thing related to Japanese encodings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash#Usage

Comment: @cypher Are you saying we should keep the backslash as yen symbol?

Comment: The alternative is to not use Japanese monospaced fonts for `pre` or `code` tags, but that has the disadvantage of breaking the fixes at http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1023 and making preformatted tables no longer line up, so on balance I'd say we should unless there's another way of working around this

Comment: We could stop using Japanese monospaced fonts for `code` but not `pre` tags as well I suppose, but even then I seem to recall that it can't be guaranteed some Windows computers which have their locale set to Japanese won't display backslashes as Yen symbols (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯", escaping the backslash with another backslash. A single backslash here just escapes the `_` underscore, which can be used in place of the `*` asterisk for emphasis.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The rendering inside backticks, `<pre>` or `<code>` blocks converts backslashes to yen symbols for me too (when using double-backslash for escaping).